Laravel artisan run comands after Cloud Run deployed
How to run scripts correctly according to the Google Cloud Run idea, commands like php artisan migrate.

It is incorrect to write this command in the Dockerfile, because this file was invented to build a container, instead of running code scripts.
⚠️ I know it's possible, but inconsistent with the idea..
There is no solutions to connect by SSH to running Cloud Run container (to run some commands).
I used to think that Cloud Run Jobs would do the trick, but not.

The questions is, How should it be done according to the idea?
App need run some scripts after deployments, so maybe Cloud Run isn't for this case?

I have no experience with Google Cloud Run, but according to this tutorial you should be able to SSH into the VM > https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-run-remote-commands-on-google-cloud-platformgcp

Seems like Creating a Cloud Run job as stated in the link will do the trick.

It is safe to run "php artisan migrate" after the deploy, but it should also contain "--force" as without it, the migration will not run in production. If you have access to the docker exec command you can also do "docker exec your_container_name php artisan migrate --force"
